# Retag request: [thunderjet] to [thunder-jet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

The English name is "THUNDER JET", so our tag should be [thunder-jet](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thunder-jet), not [thunderjet](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thunderjet).

Comment: A note: [This](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6469/274) is the only question with this tag but it cannot be retagged due to being too minor of a change to the tag name.

Comment: Another note: These sorts of retags can be done by ordinary users, but the process is fairly annoying. Specifically, the tag on the question needs to be first replaced by something else. Then one has to wait for the tag deletion script to run, which happens once per day (typically around 3:00 UTC if I remember correctly). After that you can add the correct tag. I've done this a few times so I know it works. It's an annoying procedure and usually easier just to get a mod to do it here or in chat if there's more than one or two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most honorable [@Krazer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/krazer) has [corrected this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/6469/revisions) but is too humble to post an answer here.

Comment: Krazer-san for president. :3